# webpack 2 historyApiFallback is not working, 404 not found

Tags: gruntjs, webpack-dev-server, html5-history

I just use simple grunt-webpack and it is not working.
Always get 404. I need to use the Angular 2 router I can see webpack-dev-server is not working, **not serving**.

In the config I tried:

```
 output: {
        path: root(folder.build.dist.root),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/index.html'
        },
        stats: true,
        inline: true,
        progress: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a fixed it!
I was using grunt-webpack, so the config devServer not working.
I had to add the devServer config with grunt like this:

```
"webpack-dev-server": {
        options: {
            webpack: webpackConfigDev,
        },
        'cory-run': webpackConfigDev.devServer
    },
```